# Facebook automatically logs into our website

Tags: facebook, authentication, web

So we are making a website( http://e-haaletus.azurewebsites.net/) for our school project and we are using Facebook to authenticate users. But the problem is that when you are already logged into Facebook then the website will log in automatically. Also if you log out("click me" button) then it logs out from Facebook too. We use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2 tutorial for that. And we have no idea how to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

the behavior you are noticing is by default

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2

see here on "Logging people in"